# Inheriting constructors from a template base class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, inheritance, visual-studio-2013

I have a class derived from `std::map<...>`, but I can't figure out how to make it inherit all of map's constructors (using VS2013).

Code:

```
template<class To>
class Map : public std::map<istring, To> {
public:
    using std::map::map;
};
```

Produces `'std::map' : use of class template requires template argument list`.

Trying it with different types:

```
template<class N, class M>
class A {
public:
  explicit A(int x) {}
};

class B : public A<int, int> {
  using A::A; // Ok
};
template<class M>
class C : public A<int, M> {
  using A::A; // An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
  using A<int, M>::A; // 'A<int,M>' : symbol cannot be used in a member using-declaration
};
```

Adding namespace:

```
namespace a {
  template<class N, class M>
  class A {
  public:
    explicit A(int x) {}
  };
}
template<class M>
class C : public a::A<int, M> {
  using a::A::A; // Ok
};
```

**Update:** it seems that VC2013 doesn't support inheriting constructors at all?

```
class A {
public:
  A(int x) {}
};
class B : public A {
public:
  using A::A;
};

B b(3); // 'B::B(const B &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const B &'
```

Comment: Why do you inherit from `std::map`? It is generally discouraged to do that since there are problems because all standard containers do not have virtual destructors so `std::map<...> * boom = new Map` followed by `delete boom` is undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't have any new members in the derived type so I don't need to override the destructor.

Comment: @MadScientist Then again there is no reason to do that is there?

Comment: I need to add `has` functions to maps/sets because writing `x.find(y)!=x.end()` every time is long and unreadable. Furthermore, I don't see how it is relevant to the question in the first place.

Comment: You should never inheriting from std containers, they are not designed for that. You should make `has` being a plain function.

Comment: Have you tried `using std::map<istring, To>::map;` ?

Comment: @SergeRogatch: yes, same error as in the A<int,M>::A case. It seems that VS2013 doesn't support constructor inheritance at all =(

Comment: Why not just use `x.count(y)`? It's just as fast as `x.find(y)!=x.end()` because `std::set` and `std::map` have a uniqueness constraint.

Comment: @riv, no, it doesn't, here is the page saying that "inheriting constructors" are not supported: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: The code with the namespace solution shouldn't compile. As for the internal compiler error, that is also a bug. You can report them.