# Inherit base constructor with base class being a template parameter (MSVC)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, visual-studio-2017, using

I try to achieve this code using VS2017, and get errors :

```
template <class T>
class A {
    public :
    A() {}
};

template < template <class U> class T, class U>
class B : public T<U> {
    using T<U>::T;//Errors : # 'T': is not a member of 'A<U>' # 'T': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
};

int main() {
    B<A, int> test;
    return 0;
}
```

Works perfectly using Clang and GCC according to https://wandbox.org/

I'd like to know why it's not working on Visual Studio, and how to fix it. Looks like VS doesn't want to consider second 'T' parameter as a template.

Here is another question previously asked the closest I could find about this matter. Couldn't find a solution reading it though :
[Inheriting constructors from a template base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245717/inheriting-constructors-from-a-template-base-class)

Comment: So, VS's support for delegating constructors is broken, in this case. Try, as a workaround: `typedef T<U> base_t; using base_t::base_t;`

Comment: Excellent workaround, thanks. So is it a bug in msvc or rather a compilation policy ?

Comment: Looks like a compilation bug to me. I don't recall, offhand, which language revision introduced "meta-templates" -- whether it was C++11, or later. But, whether it's lack of support of the requisite language standard, or a compiler bug, doesn't seem it would matter a lot. It is what it is.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Feel free to add an answer based on your comment. I'll happily validate it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `using base_t::base_t;` does indeed require C++11, FTR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to define a typedef alias

```
typedef T<U> base_t;
```

and use it to inherit the constructors from the base class:

```
using base_t::base_t;
```

This is not a unique compiler bug; I dimly recall a similar issue with an old version of gcc.